# How can I receive the widget resizing signal?

Tags: c++, qt

the resizeEvent function does not work when I define the window with the size of the window, please help.

I tested this function with Main Window and UI Form and answered, but did not work in my code.

Thanks.

**main.cpp**

```
    Keypad *keypad;
    keypad = new Keypad();
    keypad->Widget_Keypad->show();
```

**Keypad.cpp**

```
#include "keypad.h"

Keypad::Keypad()

{
    CreateUi();
}

void Keypad::resizeEvent(QResizeEvent *e)
{
    qDebug() << e->size().width();
}

void Keypad::CreateUi()
{
    Widget_Keypad = new QWidget;
    Vertical_Layout = new QVBoxLayout;

    Hlayout_ShowRange = new QHBoxLayout;
    
    lbl_ShowRange = new QLabel;  

    lbl_ShowRange->setText( "0 ~ 999" );
    
    Hlayout_ShowRange->addWidget( lbl_ShowRange );
    
    Vertical_Layout->addLayout( Hlayout_ShowRange );
    
    Widget_Keypad->setLayout( Vertical_Layout );
}
```

Comment: You have to inherit your Keypad from QWidget.

Comment: A C++ introduction about virtual methods may be useful.